# ApplicationUser model is missing in mode class field when trying to create new controller

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

Missing ApplicationUser:

[image]

ApplicationUser in model:

[image]

So i try to make User Manager by creating controller with ApplicationUser as model, but i can't find it on model class

Comment: Rebuild your solution.

Comment: @CodeCaster i do, but still missing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the same problem but I solved it by creating another model class which does not inherit from identity and fetch the data to it and manage it with empty controller.

The model:

```
 public class MyUser
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

and in the Controller:

```
        public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var users = _context.Users.Select(x => new MyUser
        {
            Email=x.Email,
            FirstName=x.FirstName,
            Id=x.Id,
            LastName=x.LastName,
            UserName=x.UserName
        }).ToList();
        return View(users);
    }
```

then generate your view.